# Struggling, SOS

Tags: arrays, c, structure

Have no idea how to solve this: need to find maximum element in structure. I'm calling function but it doesn't work as expected

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct str{
int num[5];
};

int main()
{
struct str arr_nums[5];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
printf("Enter number: ");
scanf("%d", &arr_nums[i].num);
}


int res = max_num(arr_nums);//calling function 
printf("Max num: %d", res);//but it prints out fantastic numbers, not related to my code
return 0;
}

int max_num(struct str*arr_nums[5]){//function that should find max
int MAX = -1;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(MAX>arr_nums[i])
    {MAX=arr_nums[i];}
}
return MAX;
}
```

Comment: Does your code even compile? It has syntax errors so I don't see how it could.

Comment: And there should be compiler warnings as well. Those are actually bugs. Concentrate on getting your code to compile without errors and without warnings first.

Comment: Thats not how collect an array in c use like this `int max_num(struct str * arr_nums)`

Comment: `if(MAX>arr_nums[i].num)` should be `<`

Comment: Are you supposed to have an array of structs that have an array of numbers in them? Take a look at your assignment and verify if you're supposed to be able to type in 5 numbers or 25 numbers. I feel like it's either a single struct with an array of numbers or an array of structs with one number in each.

Answer (score 0):

> it can be done much simpler but to utilize structs this compiles and works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int arr[5];
} numbers;

int max_num(numbers m) {//function that should find max
    int MAX = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        if(MAX < m.arr[i]) {
            MAX = m.arr[i];
        }
    }
    return MAX;
}


int main() {
    numbers Nums;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
        int a;
        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &a);
        Nums.arr[i] = a;
    }

    int res = max_num(Nums);//calling function 
    printf("\t\tMax num: %d\n\n", res);// print result
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! But the main idea here is to use structures

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to find the maximum value in an array.

If so, just keep checking for the maximum value:

```c
int max = -1; // Assuming the values are >= 0
for(int i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    if (array_element[i] > max) {
        max = array_element[i];
    }
}
```

This idea can be extended to other use cases. Start at the smallest possible value, and compare all the elements, keeping track of the largest value discovered up to that point. Eventually you'll find the largest value in the structure.

Hope this helped.